# Months difference in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider a datetime field `Fld1`.

How can I check whether this value is older than 3 months ago using a SQL query?

Comment: What do you want to do depending on whether the check passes or fails? Can you give a bit more description of the high level task you are trying to solve?

Comment: "in the last three months or older" - so you want everything in the past?

Comment: @OMG good catch -- my edit tried to clean up the English, but I left that part alone :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your other questions, it looks like SQL Server.

The 2 SQL Server answers already given are not [SARGable (link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable); they cannot utilize indexes.

```
WHERE datecolumn < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
```

Construct a date 3 months ago and test against it; this will be able to use indexes.  This statement holds true for any DBMS.

If you are after full calendar months, e.g.

- current date = 24-Feb-2011
- 3 months ago = Nov - 2010 (ignoring day of month)
- required = any date in Nov-2010 and earlier

```
WHERE datecolumn <= DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) -2, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Server:**

```
select * from table where DATEDIFF(m, dateColumn, GETDATE()) < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Microsoft SQL Server T-SQL):

Try the [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

```
... WHERE DATEDIFF(month, Fld1, GETDATE()) >= 3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Fld1 <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

This will select elements older than 3 months. If you want elements newer than three months ago, just change `<=` to `>=`.